# What does "ws" stand for on json.org?

Tags: json

From [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

```
object
    '{' ws '}'
    '{' members '}'
```

What does `ws` mean in the above? (I don't think it means web service, for example.)

Comment: It's on the bottom of the sidebar area: `ws
""
'0020' ws
'000A' ws
'000D' ws
'0009' ws
`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user didn't read the entire page they are asking about.

Comment: no where it expands the abbrevation - ws stands for white space. @PeterB, if it does then please share it here.

Comment: Peter is correct that "ws" is just a name for one of these ASCII characters (which, let's be honest, not everyone would immediately would recognize as the codes for space, tab, carriage return, etc.), it's still a valid question why they called it "ws" and not "xyz" - and they called it "ws" as an (unnecessary) shorthand for whitespace. Note that in the graphics on the left they did use the full word "whitespace", so I don't know why they decided to use the shorthand on the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here 'ws' is short for whitespace.

Comment: could you please upvote, if you think its valid Q. I see others hurting me with out comments.